# Map Reduce job on EMR successfully running but no output data on S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

Im running MR job on EMR master host.
My input file is in S3 and output set to a table in Hive via Hcatalog.
The job is running successful and i do see reducers output rows but looking at the S3 new partitions folder i can only see MR 0 byte SUCCESS file but no actual data files.
note- when reducer stage start i do see files writes to S3 into temp folder, but it seems the last operation throws the files somewhere.
I don't see any errors in MR logs.

Relevant MR driver code:"

> Job job = Job.getInstance();
>
> job.setJobName("Build Events");
>
> job.setJarByClass(LoggersApp.class);
>
> job.getConfiguration().set("fs.defaultFS", "s3://my-bucket");
>
> // set input paths Path[] inputPaths = "file on s3";
>
> FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPaths); // set input output
>
> format job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
>
> job.setOutputFormatClass(HCatOutputFormat.class);
>
> _configureOutputTable(job);
>
> private void _setReducer(Job job) {
>   job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
>   job.setOutputValueClass(DefaultHCatRecord.class); }
>
> private void _configureOutputTable(Job job) throws IOException {
>   OutputJobInfo jobInfo =
>
> OutputJobInfo.create(_cli.getOptionValue("hive-dbname"),
>   _cli.getOptionValue("output-table"), null);    HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(job, jobInfo);    HCatSchema schema =
>   HCatOutputFormat.getTableSchema(job.getConfiguration());
>
> HCatFieldSchema partitionDate = new HCatFieldSchema("date",
>   TypeInfoFactory.stringTypeInfo, null);    HCatFieldSchema
>
> partitionBatchId = new HCatFieldSchema("batch_id",
>
> TypeInfoFactory.stringTypeInfo, null);
>
> schema.append(partitionDate);    schema.append(partitionBatchId);
>
> HCatOutputFormat.setSchema(job, schema);
>       }

Any help?

Comment: You said that output is set to Hive table, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, via hcatalog and the table remain empty. Btw when running the same on hdfs I/O all work fine.

Comment: remove the above log and update with your code if possible . That will get you solution quickly

Comment: attached job code

Comment: Anyone experience such thing?